# Android Exception : org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG

Tags: android, eclipse, web-services, soap

I am trying to consume .Net webservice. I am getting the following exception.

Exception :
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@40d66380)

```
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import com.example.webserviceactivity.R;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private final String URL = "http://10.0.2.2:2351/Service1.asmx";
    private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/HelloWorld";
    private final String METHOD_NAME = "HelloWorld";
    private String TAG = "Result";
    private static String c;

    Button b;
    TextView tv;
    EditText et;
    EditText et2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);



        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_result);
        //Button to trigger web service invocation
        b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        //Button Click Listener
        b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {





                    //Create instance for AsyncCallWS
                    AsyncCallWS task = new AsyncCallWS();
                    //Call execute 
                    task.execute();
                //If text control is empty

            }
        });
    }

    public void getSum() {

        Log.i(TAG, "1");
        //Create request
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);







        //Create envelope
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        //envelope.dotNet = true;
        //Set output SOAP object
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        //Create HTTP call object
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

        Log.i(TAG, "5");

        try {
            //Invole web service
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
            //Get the response
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) envelope.getResponse();
            //Assign it to Sum static variable
            c = response.toString();

            Log.i(TAG, "6");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i(TAG, e.toString());
            c=e.toString();
        }
    }

    private class AsyncCallWS extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            Log.i(TAG, "doInBackground");
            getSum();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
            tv.setText(c + " ! ");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            Log.i(TAG, "onPreExecute");
            tv.setText("Calculating...");
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            Log.i(TAG, "onProgressUpdate");
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: please paste your full LogCat trace, before this exception , are you getting any null pointer exception?

Comment: No..Iam not getting null pointer exception

Comment: i think you have implemented this hello world webservice on your system.  Open ur wsdl and copy namespace from their @ http://10.0.2.2:2351/Service1.asmx. It must be something else.

Answer (score 0):

Download the latest jar (ksoap2-android-assembly-3.2.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar)
here is the code

```
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, Constants.METHOD_NAME_GETPROFILE);
        SoapObject userObject=new SoapObject(Constants.NAMESPACE, "user");
        userObject.addProperty("userName", username);
        userObject.addProperty("password", password);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        // envelope.dotNet = true;
        //envelope.avoidExceptionForUnknownProperty=true;
         request.addProperty("",userObject);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.implicitTypes = true;
        envelope.dotNet = true;

        HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE(Constants.URL);
        transport.debug=true;
        transport.call(Constants.SOAP_ACTION_GETPROFILE, envelope);

        //SoapObject object=(SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn; 
         System.out.println("Request :"+transport.requestDump);
         System.out.println("Response :"+transport.responseDump);

         System.out.println("TEST   "+envelope.bodyIn);
```

- In my case I am sending user as SoapObject , otherwise send propitiates .